# Uncaught (in promise) Error: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '_RUNTIME_')

Tags: javascript, reactjs, debugging, runtime-error, runtime

I got a React (v18) project and I've done something that now causing the error appear in the dev tools. Doesn't seem to break any of my flows. The error does not point me to any of my code lines, but VJPCOI.js:920

The full error message is

> Uncaught (in promise) Error: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '*RUNTIME*')
> at wrappedSendMessageCallback (ZSVJPCOI.js:920:22)
> w

The source of this error is in this function

```
const wrappedSendMessageCallback = ({
        reject,
        resolve
      }, reply) => {
        if (extensionAPIs.runtime.lastError) {
          if (extensionAPIs.runtime.lastError.message === CHROME_SEND_MESSAGE_CALLBACK_NO_RESPONSE_MESSAGE) {
            resolve();
          } else {
            reject(new Error(extensionAPIs.runtime.lastError.message)); <-- error here
          }
        } else if (reply && reply.__mozWebExtensionPolyfillReject__) {
          reject(new Error(reply.message));
        } else {
          resolve(reply);
        }
      };
```

Recommend me a good way to troubleshoot/debug this error. I was not able to find any related topics in here. I don't know where to start...

Comment: I restarted my old project, and i suffered the same problem now. I remember that there had been no problem about it, but it occurs now. It seems no more other big problem, but the red 'x' at the console logger.

Comment: see the answer from Chuen-Shiuan Wei below. The issue was caused by WebChatGPT Chrome extension

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Caused by chrome extension :WebChatGPT

Comment: Amazing, but how did you figure it out? I was not able to find anything on the web about this issue and specifically in relation to the extension.

Comment: Cool how you found that

Comment: wow.  that was it